# Does a view plugged into a table impact the upload of new data (into the table)

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, data-visualization

I have a view created from 3 differents tables (let's say table_A, table_B, table_C). Every day, i upload new data into this three tables, an automation process that collect a csv file from a ftp, upload this file to AWS and then run a process to upload this data (from csv) to the tables.

I created the view making a join of this 3 tables to show the data in a data visualization tool.

But Im having problems with the automation process, its taking too much time. A friend of mine say that the problem should be in the view process. There´s any document that I can prove this point?

Thanks.

Comment: Firstly : can you put your explain plan in your post?

Comment: The view would not come into play (would have no effect) until after the data is loaded. Unless you have  update-able (an instead of trigger) view which is updating and locking at the time